# Showing Entire Function is Bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function, such that $$
\lvert\, f(x+yi)\rvert\le \frac{1}{\lvert y\rvert},
$$
for all $x$ and all $y\ne 0$.

Show that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: Please put some more effort into your question. Questions that are just verbatim copies from a textbook are discouraged.

Comment: Could you give me some hints. thank you!

Comment: How to control $-1<y<1$ thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.
$$
If $z=x+iy$, then $y=\dfrac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$. We are given that
$$
\lvert y\,f(x+iy)\rvert\le 1,
$$
and hence
$$
\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n+1}-\lvert z\rvert^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n-1}\right\rvert=\left\lvert(z-\overline{z})\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\right\rvert\le 2
$$
Thus, for real $R>0$, and integer $m\ge 0$,
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n+1}-\lvert z\rvert^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n-1}\right)\,\frac{dz}{z^m}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n+1}-R^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n-1}\right)\,\frac{dz}{z^m} \\ = a_{m-2}-R^2a_m,
$$
while
$$
\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert=R}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n+1}-\lvert z\rvert^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n-1}\right)\,\frac{dz}{z^m}\right|\le \frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot 2\pi R\cdot \frac{2}{R^m}=\frac{1}{R^{m-1}}.
$$
Therefore, for all $R>0$.
$$
\lvert a_{m-2}-R^2a_m\rvert\le \frac{1}{R^{m-1}}.
$$
Letting $R\to\infty$, we obtain that $a_m$ has to be equal to zero, and so $a_{m-2}$. Hence $f\equiv0$.

Comment: About the identity " $\int_{|z|=R} \left( \sum a_z z^{n+1}-R^2\sum a_z z^{n-1}\right) = a_{m+2} - R^2 a_m$", isn't the right hand side a sum of m terms ??

Comment: Sorry, I forget that these terms are k-th derivative of $a_k$ so they are zero.

Comment: To compute the first integral to obtain $a_{m+2}-R^2a_m$, it looks like you are using the fact that $a_n=1/2\pi i \int f(z)/z^{n+1} dz$. Should the term $a_{m+2}$ really be $a_{m-2}$?

Comment: @MAM I corrected it. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

By the given condition, we may bound $f$ on the strip
$$
S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{C} : |y| \geq 1 \}.
$$
Without using some of the heavier machinery of complex analysis, I do not see an easy way to bound $\mathbb{C} - S$.

However, the maximum modulus principle informs us that on $\mathbb{C}-S$, $|f|$ must achieve its maximum on the boundary of this set. The boundary of this set are the lines $y = 1$ and $y = -1$. But on both of these we have our easy bound on $S$, thus $f$ must be bounded.

Here is an alternative short proof relying on the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem):

Assuming that in your statement above that $x$ and $y$ are both real variables, note that $f(x)$ must be $0$ for any real $x$, since 
$$
|f(x)| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|f(x+i/n) \right| \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 1/n = 0.
$$

Then since $f$ agrees with the function $0$ on all of $\mathbb{R}$, which has a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ must be in fact equal to $0$ everywhere. Therefore, $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @BigMathTimes Unfortunately, both of your proofs are not correct. First, for the maximum modulus principle you need a bounded domain. And in your second proof, $|f(x + i/n)|\le n$, not $1/n$.

Comment: You might try to salvage your first proof by using this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle It is the unbounded domain version of the maximum principle. One should check that it is applicable, though. I am not sure about that.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Interesting, thanks. I didn't know that one.