# To show an entire function is constant. (only with imaginary bound)

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $|f(z)|\leq 1/|y|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Here $f$ is entire and we express $z=x+iy$. Then is $f$ constant ?

Comment: What does the condition say for real z? Just nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Let $w\in\mathbb R$ and $r > 0$ be arbitrary. Let $C$ be the circle about $w$ with radius $r$. We have
$$
\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(z)}{z-w}\,dz = f(w)\quad\text{and}\quad\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_C(z-w)f(z)\,dz = 0.
$$
Hence,
$$
-f(w) = \frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_C\frac{r^{-2}(z-w)^2 - 1}{z-w}f(z)\,dz = \frac 1 {r^2}\cdot\frac 1 {2\pi i}\int_C\frac{(z-w)^2 - r^2}{z-w}f(z)\,dz.
$$
Now, since $\left|\frac{(z-w)^2 - r^2}{z-w}\right| = 2|\operatorname{Im}z|$ for $z\in C$, we conclude that
$$
|f(w)|\,\le\,\frac 1 {2\pi r^2}\cdot 2\pi r\cdot 2 = \frac 2 r.
$$
Letting $r\to\infty$ shows $f(w) = 0$.

BTW: Here is another answer: [Showing Entire Function is Bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174742/showing-entire-function-is-bounded?rq=1)

Comment: I have two question further. How to check $|\tfrac{(z-w)^2-r^2}{z-w}|=2|\text{Im} z|$, (for if we write $z-w=re^{i\theta}$. Then this equals to $r|e^{2i\theta}-1|$). If f(w) is shown to be 0, how about other values near the real axis ?  Thank you.

Comment: Put $\xi = z-w$. Then$$|\xi^2-r^2|^2 = |\xi|^4 - 2\operatorname{Re}(r^2\xi^2) + r^4 = 2r^4 - 2r^2\operatorname{Re}(\xi^2) = 2r^2\left(r^2 - (\operatorname{Re}\xi)^2 - (\operatorname{Im}\xi)^2\right).$$Now use that $r^2 = |\xi|^2 = (\operatorname{Re}\xi)^2 + (\operatorname{Im}\xi)^2$. Your last question should be answered by the idetity theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is a little typing error:  $2r^2 (r^2 - (\text{Re }\xi)^2 + (\text{Im }\xi)^2)$.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Otherwise it would be zero. ;)

Comment: +1: This is a beautiful solution but a bit "out of the hat", at least for me. If you have time and will it would be nice if you explained how you came up with this idea. Especially, how did you take into account the integral $\int_C (z-w)f(z)\, dz=0$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Hi, thanks. Actually, this is based on experience. ;o) I know this trick from a paper on spectral theory for operators in inner product spaces. Its name is "Locally definite operators in indefinite inner product spaces." You will find the relevant passage on page 6 (410 in journal). And I think they have it from a Gohberg-Krein book.

Comment: Is [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002080050082) the paper you mention?

Comment: Yes, that is it. :)

Answer (score 0):

A function like this must be zero. Indeed, let $g(z) := f(1/z)$, $z\neq 0$. Then $|g(z)|\le\frac{|z|^2}{|y|}$, i.e., $|g(z)|\le\frac 1 {|\operatorname{Im} z|}$ for $z\in\mathbb D\setminus\{0\}$. From this, it follows that $z=0$ is (at most) a pole of $g$. From here, it should be easy for you to deduce that $f = 0$.

Comment: I am perhaps overlooking something, but why does $|g(z)|\le\frac 1 {|\operatorname{Im} z|}$ imply that $z=0$ is not an essential singularity of $g$?

Comment: Well, essentially (;-)) because otherwise terms like $z^{-2}$ would let it grow faster. But I am about to make this more rigorous.

Comment: I couldn't get this straight. However, I am pretty sure it holds because $g$ is holomorphic outside zero. I posted another answer which is more comprehensible.

Comment: What I wrote about $g$ is true ($0$ must be a pole). One can use a similar argument as Yiorgos S. Smyrlis in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174742/showing-entire-function-is-bounded?rq=1